# DB Insert if not present - Spring Integration

Tags: spring, spring-integration

We have a int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter --> a transformer --> a filter --> another transformer --> int-jdbc:outbound-channel-adapter (to insert in table_1) 
(considering --> as channels)

I want to change this flow to insert into 2 tables instead of 1 but for table_2 I want to insert only if data corresponding to some fields in the message is already not present in the table i.e. insert if not present.

One thing I figured is that I will now need a pub-sub-channel with ignore-failures=false to split the flow into 2 tables.

My question is that what component should I use to select the data to check if data exists in table_2? I first thought inbound-channel-adapter is the right choice but couldn't figure out how to slide it between 2 components i.e. say a transformer and outbound-channel-adapter.

Some things I can think of are:
1. Use a filter, passing it jdbcTemplate so that the filter itself can fire a JDBC query to accept if record doesn't exist.
2. Use a outbound-channel-adapter and the insert query should have the check for data existence also, something like insert-if. I am not sure if Oracle has something like this. I am researching.

Please point me to an example or documentation or tell me the best way.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use

```
<chain>
    <header-enricher>
        <header name="original" expression="payload"/>
    </header-enricher>
    <int-jdbc:outbound-gateway query="SELECT count(*) from TABLE where ..."/>
    <filter expression="payload == 0"/>
    <transformer expression="headers.original"/>
</chain>
```

From other side `<filter>` with `JdbcTemplate` direct usage is good choice too.

Re. `insert-if`. It can work too if you have a unique constraint on the table. In this case an Exception will be thrown. And if you have `<publish-subscribe-channel ignore-failures=false>`, it would work too.

Comment: int-jdbc:outbound-gateway sounds like a good option. Thanks. I am still not clear why did you introduce the "original" header. Thanks.

Comment: Because, `<int-jdbc:outbound-gateway>` is a `MessageHandler` and it produce a `replyMessage` with payload as a result of that SELECT. So, the next `<filter>` gets deal with `int` `payload` - the `count(*)` result. But you really need to INSERT that `payload`, which has been before that `count(*)`. So, this `original` header trick comes to the rescue

Comment: Got it. I am right now struggling to use the original payload in the select query (I need to use some fields in the where clause). Do I need to write a request-sql-parameter-source-factory using the original payload? What is the best book/article to understand integration from scratch? Much appreciated !

Comment: It isn't clear to me where you have an issue: http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/latest-ga/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-outbound-gateway. I don't see reason for you to get deal with that `original`, because it is just the same `payload` object.